# Textfield is blurred after each key stroke after updating the local component state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am creating a free resume builder at https://2ct94.csb.app/, in `Education.js` I have achieved to update the local state using Vanilla JS inside `handleChange()` function. But in UI when I type in each education field, the box is getting blurred.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    const id = e.target.name.split("_").pop();
    const field = e.target.name.split("_")[0];

    const objIndex = educations.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === id);
    // console.log("Before update: ", educations[objIndex]);
    educations[objIndex][field] = e.target.value;
    // console.log("After update: ", educations[objIndex]);
    setEducations([...educations]);
  };
```

I want to keep all the fields editable while creating the flow. The source code is available at https://codesandbox.io/s/2ct94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```js
          <EducationFormPart
            key={uuidv4()}
```

React uses keys to track component identity across renders.  By generating a unique ID *every* time this renders, you are always telling React "destroy the old instance of this component, and create a new one".

**Never use keys that are randomly generated while rendering!**

For more details, see the ["Keys and Reconciliation" section of my post "A Mostly Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#keys-and-reconciliation).